# Dynamically generated tasks in task group Airflow and condition for EmailOperator

Tags: airflow, jira

I want to build the next dag in airflow
[image: Airflow process]

If there are new tickets in the **search_jira_tickets** task, then return me a list of tickets that I should process according to the scheme above. **There are few problems:**

1. I get airflow exception **TypeError: 'XComArg' object is not iterable** when I iterate over the list, returned by the function serch_new_jira_tickets(). I need iteration because one ticket can be good and another not. Here is my dag:

```
@task
def serch_new_jira_tickets():
    jql = 'MY_JQL_QUERY'
    issues_list = jira.search_issues(jql)
    if issues_list:
        return issues_list
    else:
        raise AirflowSkipException('No new issues found')

@task
def check_ticket(issue):
    ...

@task
def process_ticket(issue):
   ...

with DAG(
    dag_id='update_tickets',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@hourly'
) as dag:

    new_tickets = serch_new_jira_tickets()
    for ticket in new_tickets:
        with TaskGroup(group_id='process_funds_jira_tickets') as group:
            email_manager = EmailOperator(
                task_id='send_email',
                to='me@example.com',
                subject='Value in jira ticket was updated',
                html_content='Value in ticket has been updated',
                dag=dag)
            check_ticket = check_ticket(ticket)
            process_ticket = process_ticket(ticket)
            check_ticket >> process_ticket >> email_manager
    
    new_tickets >> group
```

2. I don't know how to create a condition for **EmailOperator**, under which it would be executed only if the jira ticket one of the fields == 100, otherwise nothing should happen. I.e. if one of the value in **process_ticket** task == 100 than process **email_manager** task, otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem I think what you want is the new [Dynamic Task Mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html) feature in Airflow 2.3. Prior to this version, any kind of for loop on a variable number of Tasks can only be done with some hacks.

Assuming you are able to use Airflow 2.3 you need to modify your task `serch_new_jira_tickets` (sic) to return a list of tickets. If there are no tickets, it should return an empty list.

You can then remove your TaskGroup and do this:

```
new_tickets = serch_new_jira_tickets()
checked = check_ticket.expand(ticket=new_tickets)
processed = process_ticket.expand(ticket=checked)
emailed = email_manager.expand(subject=processed)
```

I think the EmailOperator would need to be tweaked as well, but I'm not sure how you are passing in the template parameters. Perhaps your process_ticket task returns `subject` strings?

```
    email_manager = EmailOperator.partial(
        task_id='send_email',
         to='me@example.com',
         subject='Value in jira ticket was updated',
         html_content='Value in ticket has been updated',
         dag=dag)
```

For your second problem I suspect you want to use the ShortCircuitOperator. You would then add two more tasks... one ShortCircuitOperator that calls the EmailOperator, or a dummy task.

Comment: What if we want to keep the task groups in the DAG to keep an independant sub-dags style ? For instance I don't necessarily want to wait for all check_ticket tasks to be completed before starting all the process_ticket tasks